# I feel an answer should be accepted and maybe also downvoted. Am I insane?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, accepted-answer

(Answers indicating other reasons why I might be insane are slightly OT.)

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297875/i-find-myself-reversing-accumulators-at-the-end-of-most-functions-how-can-i-sto) recently which was answered quickly in a manner that directly addressed my concern.  This answer addressed my question in a different fashion than other answers which I think is helpful.  However, it also (arguably?) demonstrates a bad pattern and probably shouldn't be used in general.  The answer has since been modified to include a minor caveat mentioning this disadvantage.

The answer is exactly what I was looking for and thus is accepted (checkmark), but given the poor results of using that code in practice, I don't think it deserves an upvote.  It might even be deserving of a downvote.  (At this time it has received enough downvotes that it doesn't need me to dogpile on it.)

Am I insane?  Is accepting an answer and almost downvoting it as well bizarre and unhelpful behavior on my part?

(I have since moved the accepted checkmark to another answer after re-reading the meaning of the checkmark.)

Comment: The real question here is why you're actually using a solution that you know full well you shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm not using that solution.  But academically, that answers the question very directly.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be accepting it.  You should be accepting the answer you're actually using, not just an answer that is "technically an answer to the question, even though it's not actually useful to me".

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I'll review the FAQ to ensure I don't make similar mistakes in the future.

Comment: According to the Tour: "Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked." By this criteria @Servy is correct and I will unaccept the answer if I can.

Comment: You can always unaccept an answer.

Comment: Do you need help getting the question downvoted?  Just mention it, meta users are usually happy to oblige.  Or consider editing it.

Comment: I'm welcome to consider suggestions on how to improve my question. @HansPassant

Comment: @Will Erm, you might want to mention you're making a joke about OP's username... took me a bit to realize you weren't trying to say that some race of people is insane.

Comment: @MageXy Hah!  I hadn't even thought about that!

Comment: @MageXy - Wait, what did you think Will meant about the vegetable part then?

Comment: @BSMP That's what made me look back at the comment in the first place. It seemed so random. If he hadn't added that part, I might have flagged his comment, completely oblivious that the joke flew over my head. ([I am not a clever man.](http://buttersafe.com/2008/10/23/the-detour/))

Answer (score 9):

Since you're not actually using the solution, and you don't think that it is a useful answer, you should not accept it.

Accepting is for an answer that is, "the most helpful in solving your problem".  This answer didn't help you solve your problem.

Since you feel (reasonably strongly, by the sound of it) that it's not a helpful answer, you should downvote it, to reflect that opinion.

Comment: (Without having read the answer) I'd hesitate to downvote since "the answer has since been modified to include a minor caveat mentioning this disadvantage". It can be quite illuminating to have a bad answer which also explains why it's bad. Technically, if the explanation is very good, it could even merit an upvote.

Comment: @Jongware Question: "How do I clean my gun?" Answer: "First, make sure that it's loaded, then disable the safety, and look down the barrel to make sure that you can see the bullet in the chamber, then [...] and oh by the way, this is extremely unsafe, so you shouldn't do any of this if you actually want to clean your gun without getting shot." No, including a minor caveat at the end of a suggestion to do something *extremely harmful* is not appropriate, and is going to cause more harm than good. Posting a good answer and then at the end, explaining why it's better than an alternative can help.

Comment: Ah, that explains why you did not start with "sure, go ahead and accept that answer. ... *however* ..." I suppose it is indeed better to assume a limited attention span and make sure the good stuff appears first.